# how to resize surface elements after resizing window in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to be able to resize the surface of my minesweeper game.
I've already read [this](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/WindowResizing) but it only works to 50%.
I do get the new width and height (after resizing) with `event.dict['size']` but the images are not positioned properly and I don't know why because the code looks right in terms of logic.

This is the normal window:

[image]

When I expand the window to the right it looks like this:

[image]

And when I make it smaller it looks like this:

[image]

Why is that ? Here is the code I made:

```
if event.type == pg.VIDEORESIZE:

        new_w, new_h = event.dict['size']

        if state.current_state == "Game":
            game.cell_width = new_w//game.COLUMNS
            game.cell_height = new_h//game.ROWS
            game_handler.render()
```

game_handler function :

```
def render(self):

    for cell in self.game.cells:
        img = pg.image.load(cell.cell_img_path)
        img = pg.transform.scale(img,(self.game.cell_width,self.game.cell_height))
        self.display.blit(img, (cell.column*self.game.cell_width,cell.row*self.game.cell_height))
        
    pg.display.update()
```

Comment: Please provide the full code so we can test

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the tiles are square, then you have to compute the minimum of the width and height of a tile. You have to round up the quotient of the window size and the number of tiles to make sure that all tiles fit in the window:

```py
def div_round_up(a, b):
    return a // b + (a % b > 0)

tile_width  = div_round_up(new_w, game.COLUMNS)
tile_height = div_round_up(new_h, game.ROWS)
square_size = min(tile_width, tile_height)

game.cell_width  = square_size 
game.cell_height = square_size
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to check if all tiles can fit into the window. Because the position of the tiles has to be an integer (1 for each pixel), after resizing, it probably happens that the (e.g.) 20 tiles of the first row cannot fit into the window wich e.g. has a width of 900 pixels after resizing it. But If the window would be resized to 1000 pixel width, then the 20 tiles would fit again because 1000%20 == 0.

The solution therefore was:

```
if event.type == pg.VIDEORESIZE:
        

        new_w, new_h = event.dict['size']   

        if new_w % game.COLUMNS != 0 or new_h % game.ROWS != 0:
            delta_width = new_w % game.COLUMNS
            delta_height = new_h % game.ROWS
            SCREEN = pg.display.set_mode((new_w - delta_width, new_h - delta_height), pg.RESIZABLE)
        else:
            SCREEN = pg.display.set_mode((new_w, new_h), pg.RESIZABLE)
```

What I did was:
After the user resized the window with his mouse, I adjusted the window size if the tiles wouldnt fit into the window perfectly.